# Convert zip/postal code to coordinates, city, county, region etc in Salesforce?

Tags: geolocation, address

Is there any possibility in Salesforce to extend on location data such as postal code and convert to coordinates, city, county, region etc?

E.g. Transform postal code: GU1 3DA and country: UK into city: Guildford, County: Surrey and Region: South East England etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  There is no built-in functionality for this.  Have you checked the AppExchange for 3rd-party apps?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at postcodes.io https://postcodes.io/docs which has an API that can probably retrieve all the information you want

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some standard objects like Leads, Contacts, & Accounts (essentially, objects that support an "Address" type field) support [automated geocoding with Data Integration Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_dot_com_clean_admin_automatically_get_geocodes_for_addresses.htm&type=5). These are easy to turn on settings within Salesforce.

Otherwise you will need to use a third party geocoding service or bring in data into your Salesforce org in such a way that you can convert an entered postal code into a given city.